# C++ class and object - memory

Tags: c++, class, object, compile-time, execution-time

Whcih occupies memory, a `class` or an `object`? And, is that at `compile` or `execution` time?

Thanks.

Comment: This question makes no (okay, to be fair: little) sense.

Comment: Hm, busy doing homework?

Comment: class & object are a part of your final executable. So what do you think ?

Answer (score 4):

During compilation, the layout of memory is an implementation detail--you don't need to know or care.

During runtime, however... in C++, classes define types but (unless you activate RTTI which allows limited introspection into classes) don't generally occupy any memory themselves<sup>1</sup>--they're just the frameworks for the construction and destruction of objects. Their *methods*, however--the constructors, destructors, instance methods, and class methods, occupy some portion of executable memory, but compilers can and do optimize away any such methods that are not used in the program.

Instances of types (that is, objects as well as primitives like `int` variables) occupy the bulk of memory in C++, but for their member functions they refer back to their classes. Exactly how much memory an instance of a particular class uses is entirely and utterly an implementation detail, and you should generally not need to care about it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even then, the classes themselves don't use the memory, but their associated `std::typeinfo` instance does. But again, this is generally implementation-y stuff and not the sort of thing even wizened programmers pay much attention to.

Comment: Static fields can be considered to occupy some memory belonging to a class.

Comment: The vtable, static members, and the member functions of a class occupy memory at runtime.

Comment: @Oli: I never said otherwise.

Comment: @Jonathan: Indeed, but your answer implied that the only class-specific data is type-info.

Comment: @Oli: read the third paragraph. "but for their member functions they refer back to their classes."

Answer (score 0):

The `object instance` is the one which occupies memory at execution time since a `class` is the blueprint of the object.

Also, in C++ there are static variables, local variables and global variables which also occupies memory.

Answer (score 0):

Static, local and global variables are stored in BBS data segment, while objects are stored either in heap or in stack.
Objects are the instances of class, while class definition is used by compiler to create an object by it's class description. Class is like an instruction of "how to build table by yourself" that occupies only the paper it's written on, while an object is the real table made by yourself according to the instruction, that occupies the real space.